# MySQL Select Week Range From Database

Tags: mysql, sql, week-number

In my database I am storing week numbers and the relating years. For example something like this:

```
id | week | year | text
---+------+------+-----------
 1 |  23  | 2012 | hello
 2 |  27  | 2012 | something
 3 |  39  | 2012 | more text
 4 |  43  | 2012 | more text
```

Then on the front end the user can select a week and a year and I then want to be able to return all records between that range. For example selecting between week 25 - 2012 and week 50 - 2012 would return the last 3 records.

I'm not sure whether it will be easier to also hold the first date of the week as well and search on this or if there is a way to search on weeks easily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `... WHERE (year = 2012) AND (week BETWEEN 25 AND 50)`. won't work if you allow the query range to span across different years, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you want consecutive weeks, even when the year is different.  To do this, some arithmetic helps:

```
select text
from dates
where year*100 + week between $weekmin+$yearmin*100 and $weekmax+$yearmax*100
```

This converts, say, week 7 in 2012 to "201207" for comparison purposes.

Comment: Wow, easier than I thought. +1 for that :)

Comment: @palindrom . . . yes.  Good catch.  It seems I deleted that somewhere along the way.

Comment: I would have never thought of this in a million years. Very very clever and works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Well since MySQL supports [comparison operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html) this task is really easy:

```
SELECT text FROM `dates` WHERE week>=$weekmin AND week<=$weekmax AND year>=$yearmin AND year<=$yearmax ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for both your replies but I need to be able to span multiple years and this is the problem I have come across and can't get around.

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't think of that the first time. I will need a minute to figue this out.
But using DATE or UNIX timestamp instead of two ints would spare you of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE week >= User_input1_week
AND week <= User_input2_week
AND year >= User_input1_year
AND year <= user_input2_year
```

This would probably work.

> I'm not sure whether it will be easier to also hold the first date of
>   the week as well and search on this or if there is a way to search on
>   weeks easily.

Using the DATE type for your column would probably be a better move.